# Getting data from Soap response stdclass object in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I use following method to get webservice data,

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://empblr.dyndns.org/CentralHomeDelivery_Mob/Service.asmx?wsdl");


     $result = $client->GetAlladdress(array('customerid'=>36));
```

When I var_dump $result I get,

```
object(stdClass)[16]
  public 'GetAlladdressResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'schema' => string '<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Table"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="AdressID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="CustomerID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="LocationID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs'... (length=1030)
      public 'any' => string '<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet xmlns=""><Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><AdressID>643</AdressID><CustomerID>36</CustomerID><LocationID>176</LocationID><StreetName>asdf</StreetName><HouseNo>1234</HouseNo><AlternatePhone>5632256</AlternatePhone><LandMark>asdf </LandMark><MainLocID>2</MainLocID><locName>ANDOLANA CIRCLE</locName><MainLoc>Mysore    </MainLoc></Table><Table diffgr:id="Table2" m'... (length=1864)
```

How I can get the value from child node `<CustomerID>` and store into an array??

Thank you..

Comment: This is obviously not the whole output of the `var_dump`. As long as the WSDL properly covers it, you should get some object you simply can access a property on. Otherwise use an XML parser (e.g. SimpleXML) parse the XML of the `any` property.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/SoapClient) should provide a `stdClass` object that offers these values as standard class properties *if* you're in WSDL mode.

If that is not the case (it's not clear from the `var_dump` in your question because it is cut-off) you can parse the XML you have in the `any` property, for example by using the [`SimpleXML` parser](http://php.net/simplexml).

Some code example ([Online Demo](http://eval.in/11844)):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result->GetAlladdressResult->any);

# traversal
$table = $xml->NewDataSet->Table[0];
echo $table->LocationID, "\n", $table->MainLoc, "\n";

# xpath
echo $xml->xpath('//LocationID')[0], "\n", $xml->xpath('//MainLoc')[0], "\n";
```

It shows two alternative ways to access the data, the first with standard traversal and the second via the `xpath()` method running an xpath query.

Comment: Thanks for this, and let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regexp:

```
preg_match('#<CustomerID>(\d+)</CustomerID>#', $result->GetAlladdressResult->any, $match);
$customerId = isset($match[1]) ? $match[1] : false;
```

Comment: Yh its works..thanks..but when I try to get <MainLoc> its fails :(

Comment: That's because you need different regexp for MainLoc content, it's not a number, try replacing '#<CustomerID>(\d+)</CustomerID>#' with '#<MainLoc>(\w+)</MainLoc>#'

Comment: yes! it works..Can you please help me getting the whole xml content from $result and storing it as a string?

Comment: Use preg_match_all('#<[^>]*>([^<]*)</[^>]*>#', $result->GetAlladdressResult->any, $matches); and in $matches you will find all of the content of the xml you've received

Comment: that regex is not fitting to parse valid XML. it's actually quite far off and does not offer any control like, taking the third of such child element inside that parent element and so on and so forth.

Comment: @hakre I totally agree, this is really dirty and very quick solution =)

Comment: Is there a real solution for this issue? Even though the regex works, the code is polluted now. Even with a helper function.